# Doing something in the future: I am vs I will be

Tags: usage, future-time

If I am able to do something in the future should I use **"I am able to do it in the future"** *or* **"I will be able to do it in the future"**? Is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, you should use both. They are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know, there is a difference between saying I *am* able to do something, and I *will be* able to do something.  The first says I can do it *now*, while the second says I can do it some time in the future.

*However*, we have to re-evaluate this when you add an adverb of time that is already in the future.  If I say I am able to do something *in the future*, it's not clear whether I can or can't do it *now*.  The default assumption is I *can't* do it now, otherwise I would just say that I can do it.  For example:

> When can you mow the lawn?
>
> I can do it.  (I can do it now)
>
> I am able to do it this afternoon.  (I can't -- or I don't want to -- do it now)
>
> I will be able to do it this afternoon. (I can't do it now.  Or I don't want to)

The practical result is that these two forms have the same meaning, even if they approach it in different ways.

> Can we go see a movie sometime soon?
>
> I am able to go tonight / I will be able to go tonight.

Either way, same meaning.  Native speakers use these forms interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the presence of someone or something, "I will be with you"  speaks of a time of waiting, whereas, "I am with you" says no waiting is necessary. They are not the same.